# Traductor codigo binario en java

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un proyecto que traduzca el código binario mediante botones en java.Tengo una clase con la interfaz ActionListener que es la que gestiona todos los datos de los botones. Tengo un array tipo booleano que gestiona el estado de mis botones y con el detecto que boton esta activo o inactivo. El problema es que no se me acumula el total del valor decimal.

Tengo 3 clases: La clase Main, Contenido y Contar, en la clase de Contar es donde se maneja los datos. La clase Main solo crea el marco y la lamina, la clase Contenido crea los botones , los agrega a la lamina y les pone como ActionListener la clase Contar

Clase Contar:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Contar implements ActionListener
{
    int suma, valorBoton;
    int valores[] =  {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
    int total = 0;
    boolean[] estados2 =  {false, false , false, false, false, false, false, false};
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        valorBoton = Integer.parseInt( ( (JButton) e.getSource() ).getName() );
        //VALORBOTON = NOMBRE DEL BOTON
        detectarBoton(valorBoton);


    }

    public void detectarBoton(int botonId)/*NOMBRE DEL BOTON*/
    {
        switch(botonId)
        {
            case 1:
            verificacion(1);
            break;

            case 2:
                verificacion(2);
                break;

            case 4:
                verificacion(4);
                break;

            case 8:
                verificacion(8);
                break;

            case 16:
                verificacion(16);
                break;

            case 32:
                verificacion(32);
                break;

            case 64:
                verificacion(64);
                break;

            case 128:
                verificacion(128);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void verificacion(int numero)
    {
        int index = 0; 
        Estados state = new Estados();
        switch(numero)
        {
        case 1: index = 0; break;
        case 2: index = 1; break;
        case 4: index = 2; break;
        case 8: index = 3; break;
        case 16: index = 4; break;
        case 32: index = 5; break;
        case 64: index = 6; break;
        case 128: index = 7; break;
        }

        if(state.getEstado(index) == false)
        {   
            state.setEstados(index, true);
            suma =numero;
            System.out.println("1");
        }else if(state.getEstado(index) == true)
        {
            state.setEstados(index, false);
            suma=numero;
            System.out.println("0");
        }

        actualizarTotal();
    }

    public void actualizarTotal()
    {
        Estados state = new Estados();
        for(int i = 0; i<estados2.length;i++)
        {
            if(estados2[i])
            {
                if(suma == 0)
                {
                    total = total +1;
                }else {
                    total = (int) (total +(Math.pow(2, i)));
                }

            }

            if(estados2[i] == false) {
                if(suma == 0)
                {
                    total = total -1;
                }else {
                    total = (int) (total -(Math.pow(2, i)));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Actualizado total:" + total);
    }

    private class Estados
    {


        public Estados() {

        }

        public boolean getEstado(int valor)
        {

            return estados2[valor];

        }

        public void setEstados(int valor, boolean estado)
        {
            estados2[valor] = estado;
            //System.out.print(" ,setEstados(" + valor + ") = " + estados2[valor]);
        }
    }
}
```

El error es un error en tiempo de compilacion y ocurre en la clase contar en el metodo verificacion(int numero) y actualizarTotal()

Comment: mmm y cual es el error? agregalo en la pregunta. mas si es un error en tiempo de compilacion, que suelen decir cual es el problema

Comment: agrega try catch para saber el error que te muestra, ademas es necesario crear un switch si siempre llamas al mismo método ??